# layout change with screen size

Tags: android, xml

I have created an xml file.But problem is that when the screen size of mobile changes there are some changes in design.I have searched but still confused.Wat i want is that wat to do so that design remains same on every mobile and must not depend on its screen size.Following is my xml file-

**player.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="6"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="#fff">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="@drawable/backbtn"
                android:textSize="19dp"
                android:id="@+id/back"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="335dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:text="Welcome"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:paddingRight="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/id"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/plname"
            android:text="ABC XYZ"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:background="#7ee77c"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/plid"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plname"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Player ID:"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="right|center"
                android:background="#7ee77c"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/plidtxt"
                android:text="1000"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:background="#7ee77c"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                />




    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="29dp"
                android:id="@+id/day"
                android:layout_below="@id/line2"
                android:text="Wednesday"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:gravity="right|center"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="29dp"
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_below="@+id/line2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/day"
                android:text="05/04/2017"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="29dp"
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_below="@id/line3"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date"
                android:text="12.00"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                />



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >
        <SearchView
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"

            android:queryHint="Search"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/day"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        >


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Sr"
                android:id="@+id/sr"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:background="#b27ce7"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Player Name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sr"
            android:id="@+id/player"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:background="#b27ce7"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="28dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/a"
                android:layout_weight="0.12"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/player"
                android:background="#b27ce7"

                />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/a"
            android:id="@+id/rank"
            android:text="Rank"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#b27ce7"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="27dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/b"
                android:layout_weight="0.12"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rank"
                android:background="#b27ce7"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#b27ce7"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:text="Team"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="330dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:id="@+id/pllist"
            android:background="#ffff"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listline1"

            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:id="@+id/update"
            android:background="#4e57a9"
            android:text="Update"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_above="@+id/delete"
             />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#4e57a9"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textColor="#000"

            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to have the exact same layout to look the same on every Android device out there. The best advice I can give you is to plan your type of layout carefully. For example you can try `ConstraintLayout`. Also, for supporting different sizes you can create a different layouts with smallest width qualifiers such as `sw600dp` and `sw720dp`. Also, take a look at this https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you juste have to define a height and width of your main Linear Layout.
Like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="100dip"
android:layout_height="200dip"
android:weightSum="6"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, this is an easy thing to do as android mostly takes care of it for you. You simply need to make a different layout file for each different screen size you want to support.

The important part is to name them the same (`example.xml`), but put them in different folders with certain tags which identify to android when they should be used. For example  `res/values/example.xml` vs `res/values-sw600dp-land/example.xml` where sw600dp and land are qualifiers to identify smallest width and landscape orientation. you can read more about it here. https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: you mean 5 copy of xml for 5 basic screen sizes? single change and cross check 5 files everytime?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean exactly. If we are just talking about the same layout being shown on devices with different displays (different size, different density, different aspect ratio), then all you need to do is name your files appropriately and android will automatically select the appropriate one for the job. There is no need for you to check anything or manually set the layout.

Comment: suppose i want my app to support 10 types of screens. i followed your steps and made 10 different folders. now i need to add a text view. i have to manually add this textview in 10 different xml layouts according to its properties. dont you think this is not a good a idea?

Comment: what you have suggested holds good when the trade off is between 2 to 3 screen types. but not all screen types. what you said is correct but not a good practice in current case.

Comment: If you have sections of your layout that will remain common across many layouts you can use the `<include>` tag. that way you can share some parts of your layout across different configurations. Aside from that, if your layout is getting quite complex, another option is to divide it up into fragments to make it more manageable.

Comment: @MohammedAtif If you created a layout with a `textview` and now you want to create 9 more layouts for supporting different screen sizes, you do not need to manually add the `textview` in each one. When you are in your `xml` file, in the `Preview` on the top right corner, next to `language` there is an icon that looks like a square with two rectangles coming out of it. Click on it and it will create the layout you need from the selected layout.

Answer (score 0):

not allocate fixed height and width to widget.use layout_weight property and set all widget.

otherwise use

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for medium-density
res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for high-density
res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap for extra-high-density
res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap for extra-extra-high-density

res/mipmap-mdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icon for medium-density
res/mipmap-hdpi/my_icon.png         // launcher icon for high-density
res/mipmap-xhdpi/my_icon.png        // launcher icon for extra-high-density
res/mipmap-xxhdpi/my_icon.png       // launcher icon for extra-extra-high-density
res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/my_icon.png      // launcher icon for extra-extra-extra-high-density
```